# jQuery initialize functions before using

Tags: jquery

I want to have a statement as

```
$(myVar).click(function(){
    // Do some stuff
});
```

This statement is in the main .js file that is included on every page. I want to then have `myVar` defined in different files on different pages and then the statement above becomes active.

How do I do that?

Comment: initialize your variable before including main.js, and you are done.

Comment: Holy crap you got a lot of answers for this one lol. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Define it like this instead...**

```
$(myVar).on('click', function(){
    // Do whatever
});
```

**And call that `handler` in your document using:**

`<script>var myVar=yourValue;</script>`

`<script src="myJs.js"></script>`

If you do it this way, you will ensure your `var` is loaded before your `script` that relies on it and your `DOM` will carry out its merry way.

**FYI -** There is no real way to share a variable between multiple pages unless you define a default in your `myJs.js` file or create a **global variable** per `HTML` doc.

Comment: u dont need to have myVar in the callback's parameter. It would be global. rather myVar will be overwritten with the event object there.

Comment: Sorry, so used to building machine learning and avoiding globals :-P

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can just the following:

**Page 1**

```
var myVar = $("#myElement");
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Page 2**

```
var myVar = $(".myElements");
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think he wanted classes and ids :-(

Comment: Eh? I just  thought myVar should contain different selectors on different pages.

Comment: As much as I agree, I didn't ask the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `myVar` before you include main.js

```
var myVar = "someThing";

--include main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the file that has the declaration of `myVar` before the script that uses it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myVarSource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="doStuffSource.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing myVar before you load main.js

```
var myVar = "whatever";
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar=$("#id");
myVar.click(function(){
    // Do some stuff
});
```

Comment: Not sure he was looking for a specific jQuery ID or Class, but rather a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In main.js add this function rather..

```
var myVarClick = function (ele) {
    // Do some stuff
    alert(ele.val());
}
```

and in each page call this function..

```
$("button").click(function () {
    myVarClick($(this));
});
```